# How to get a reference to the Animation Window?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I am animating a gameobject with the animator. I am matching the animation to a video I have overlade in the editor. At the moment I am having to adjust the video scrubber to get to the next position I want to keypoint, then calculate and change it in the animator. I would like to be able to control the animation scrubber with my video scrubber or vice versa.

[The wiki has what I need](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationWindow-frame.html) on for the animation window but I'm unsure how/if I can access the animation window through a script.

Any help appreciated thanks.

Comment: Are you hoping to do this in a build or only in the editor?

Comment: @NSJacob1 I'm only looking to do this in editor

Comment: So is your question then rather "How to get a reference to the Animation Window"?

Comment: @derHugo Yes thank you, that's a much better way of phrasing it. I will update my title to be more useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it is a bit difficult to get a specific instance of a certain built-in editor window since you can have multiple of the same type open at the same time.

However, just assuming there already is a certain `AnimationWindow` (<kbd>CTRL + 6</kbd>) window open you could simply do e.g.

```
private AnimationWindow animationWindow;

...

// If there is no AnimationWindow open this will also open one
if(animationWindow == null) animationWindow = EditorWindow.GetWindow<AnimationWindow>();

aniamtionWindow.frame = targetFrame;
```

Just as a little demo

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] [Min(0)] private int frame;

    private AnimationWindow animationWindow;

    private void Update()
    {
        if(animationWindow == null) animationWindow = EditorWindow.GetWindow<AnimationWindow>();

        animationWindow.frame = frame;
    }
}
```

[image]

Make sure to put any script that uses the `UnityEditor` namespace either in a folder called `Editor` or wrap according parts of the script with pre-processor tags (`#if UNITY_EDITOR` ... `#endif`)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thank you :D 
For anyone in the future who cannot reference `AnimationWindow` due to protection level you'll need to upgrade Unity to a version above 2019